# How to display specific css styles wp_nav_menu()

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am really new to wordpress. I have a custom menu that I would like to only display specific menu item when the users browser lands on a specific page.

wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu-main'));

Is there a way to have wp_nav_menu() hook to only display specific menu items that have specific css class items?

Comment: No, there is not.  However, research `wp_nav_menu` - you'll see that you *can* have multiple menus that you show depending on which page you are on, and further, you can "filter" the menu, so with custom code, you could construct a filter that limits which menu item(s) display in given circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, Yes, there is a way. You can use conditionals. PHP if statements. WordPress allows for you check the page title, ID, category before you execute a command e.g

```
if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) ) {

     //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
     //execute something

} else {

     //none of the page about us, contact or management is in view
     //execute something

}
```

And you can add a class/ID to the `wp_nav_menu`

So joining the two ideas, you can have:

```
// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.
if ( is_page( 42 ) ) {

    wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id' => 'pines', 'menu_class' => 'pnav'));

} elseif( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) ) {

     wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id' => 'bananas', 'menu_class' => 'nav'));

} else {

     wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id' => 'main-id', 'menu_class' => 'main-nav'));

}
```

Having added unique IDs and classes, you can style this in the way you want. 
Reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 0):

Consider searching for existing plugins prior writing custom functions. For your specific feature, I would use the [*Page Specific Menu Items*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-menu-items/) plugin.

If you would like to add to an existing function, consider using the [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) filter. With this function, you would be able to add a css class to your body element, then write css that changes how your menu appears for any specific page.